# Boostrap 5 Floating Columns split sidebar above and below main content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have not found a way to do this in Bootstrap 5 (previous stackoverflow answers appear to be all for older bootstrap versions).

I'm trying to have my main content on the left and a sidebar on the right.  The sidebar on the right contains 2 sections which, in responsive mobile view, should move above and below the main content:

[image: Desktop view vs mobile view]

Looking at the Bootstrap 5 docs it appears you should be able to float the left column to the left and the right column to the right, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 ms-auto bg-info">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 me-auto bg-success">
      Main Section
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 ms-auto bg-primary">
      Foot Notes
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone give me a working example of how to do this using the native Bootstrap 5 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [possible in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141694/one-tall-div-next-to-two-shorter-divs-on-desktop-and-stacked-on-mobile-with-boot/50145570#50145570) by "disabling" flexbox on some breakpoints.

It can also be done in Bootstrap 5 in a similar way. Use `d-md-block` to disable flexbox on md (and up). Then use floats on the appropriate columns. Below md will still use flexbox and allow the columns to naturally order and stack vertically.

```
   <div class="row d-md-block">
      <div class="col-md-8 ms-auto bg-info float-end"> Title </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 me-auto bg-success float-start">
            Main Section
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 ms-auto bg-primary"> Foot Notes </div>
   </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/eCqAxANfym)